# Understanding the SB_IO primitive in Lattice ICE40

Tags: verilog, fpga, lattice, yosys, ice40

I am playing with [cliffordwolf/picorv32](https://github.com/cliffordwolf/picorv32) and am having some problem understanding the following snippet in `picosoc` ([link to source](https://github.com/cliffordwolf/picorv32/blob/e308982e18fc952a8d446ddb7ea8b70433a998c2/picosoc/hx8kdemo.v#L57-L65)):

```
SB_IO #(
    .PIN_TYPE(6'b 1010_01),
    .PULLUP(1'b 0)
) flash_io_buf [3:0] (
    .PACKAGE_PIN({flash_io3, flash_io2, flash_io1, flash_io0}),
    .OUTPUT_ENABLE({flash_io3_oe, flash_io2_oe, flash_io1_oe, flash_io0_oe}),
    .D_OUT_0({flash_io3_do, flash_io2_do, flash_io1_do, flash_io0_do}),
    .D_IN_0({flash_io3_di, flash_io2_di, flash_io1_di, flash_io0_di})
);
```

I have found a graphic description for the `SB_IO` primitive in [Lattice iCE40 technology library documentation](http://www.latticesemi.com/~/media/LatticeSemi/Documents/TechnicalBriefs/SBTICETechnologyLibrary201504.pdf), but I still cannot understand its purpose because it's too complex for me to interpret. There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37431914/ice40-icestorm-fpga-flow-bi-directional-io-pins) about the primitive, after reading which I would assume it creates some kind of bidirectional connection, but I failed to understand how that is related to making the output pin "tristated".

I would appreciate a high-level description of the effect of the `SB_IO` cell under this particular configuration. Which pin is connected to which pin? Which are inputs and which are outputs? What is the purpose of instantiating this cell?

Comment: The only things that don't show a ready correlation between the 4 Verilog pins an the SB IO pad on P.87 of the PDF you provide the link for is what's connected to the pad pins (flash_io_buf [3:0]). .PIN_TYPE describes how the multiplexers are programmed. There is no pull-up and the latches appear unused. Is there a programming question here or are you asking a hardware question on the wrong site?

Comment: Hi @user1155120, I suppose asking about the effect of a cell instantiation count as a programming question? Here is the background in case you are interested: I have just learned the basics of Verilog, but have never seen FPGA "primitives" like `SB_IO`. The reason I am messing with this is that the instructor of my FPGA course encourages us to participate in an FPGA contest (which makes sense: that would be a great way to learn), and for that, I need to incorporate `picosoc` into my design.

Comment: @user1155120 Also, the "pad pins" `flash_io_buf [3:0]` are not used hereafter, so this instantiation must have some kind of side effects?

Comment: They're IO pins.

Comment: @user1155120 "IO pins" refer to the pins outside of the chip package, right? I thought `flash_io3, flash_io2, flash_io1, flash_io0` are IO pins, rather than `flash_io_buf [0:3]` o_O.

Comment: [This question is being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396157/how-can-i-improve-my-question-about-fpga-programming).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This instance was used because at the time Yosys didn't support tristates in Verilog well enough, it does now but in general tristate support in FPGA toolchains isn't always trusted.

It could be replaced with the following generic Verilog, repeated 4 times from 0 to 4.

```
assign flash_io0 = flash_io0_oe ? flash_io0_do : 1'bz;
assign flash_io0_di = flash_io0;
```

Comment: Thanks, that’s really helpful! I wonder what is `flash_io_buf` as mentioned above by @user1155120. Is, say, `flash_io_buf[0]` an alias of `flash_io0` after the inference/instantiation?

Comment: `flash_io_buf[0]` is the name of the SB_IO **instance**, it has nothing to do with wires or pins

Answer (score 1):

I found the following comments for the module parameters, which might go some way to explaining how to use `SB_IO`:

```
SB_IO #(
  .PIN_TYPE (6'b 1010_01),
  .PULLUP (HIGH)
) ram_d_io [15:0] (                   // Name of the cell.  Must be unique
  .PACKAGE_PIN (ram_d_inout [15:0]),  // Name of the module parameter
  .OUTPUT_ENABLE (~data_bus_we),      // Line that controls whether `ram_d_inout` is high-Z or driven
  .D_OUT_0 (data_bus_w [15:0]),       // Line that determines level when `ram_d_inout` is driven
  .D_IN_0 (data_bus_r [15:0])         // Line that is driven by `ram_d_inout` when high-Z
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my interpretation of the diagram in the documenatation (set means `1'b1` / high / True):

`SB_IO.PIN_TYPE[5:0]` config parameter by each bit index (left to right):

- 5: Set if `OUTPUT_ENABLE` input signal used (use `inout` for `PACKAGE_PIN`)
- 4: depends on 5:

  - if OE used, whether `OUTPUT_ENABLE` is registered to posedge `OUTPUT_CLK`, else the enable is direct (unregistered).
  - if no OE: `PACKAGE_PIN` is `output` else `input`
- 3: Whether `D_OUT_0` is a direct(unregistered) output else it's registered DDR along with `D_OUT_1`
- 2: depends on 3:

  - if 3: inverts the direct output when set
  - if ~3: instead swaps `D_OUT_0`/1 DDR clock phase on output latch:

    - if set: `D_OUT_O` register loads on `posedge .OUTPUT_CLK`, but is output on negedge (during clock low), vice versa for `D_OUT_1`. If clear, then `D_OUT_O` is output during clock high, and `D_OUT_1` is output during clock low.
- 1: `D_IN_0` input is latched with `LATCH_INPUT_VALUE` signal
- 0: `D_IN_0` input is direct else registered with `.INPUT_CLK`,
  with no effect if input latch enabled.
- note `D_IN_1` input is always registered to negedge `INPUT_CLK`,
  yet may be ignored for a posedge registered SDR input mode.
- `D_OUT_1` has no effect unless [3]==0, however,
  there is no SDR registered output mode!

  - you'll have to run the output as direct, and have an external register.
  - for this, typically you just let yosys infer the whole SB_IO for that pin as a direct output, maybe defined as type `output reg`.
- also note `D_OUT_1` is unable to be set on posedge clock,
  meaning if you need to set it from posedge domain, then
  all output may need to be one register later.

  - although, setting `[3]` may help with this.
- `6'b1010_01` is thus a direct (unregistered) `inout` pin.
- `6'b0010_01` is a plain input pin
- `6'b0110_01` is a plain output pin
- you rarely see those last two, because yosys will automatically infer them with sensible default settings, and can even infer the first, usually, so long as the `assign packagepin = enablesig? outputsig : 1'bz;` line is in the top level module.

  - You may see them if `.PULLUP(1'b1)` is desired, this enables the weak-high pullup resistor on that pin.
- finally, `PIN_TYPE` maps into configuration bits, you can't wire dynamic signals to them, you just choose them as constant to be set at compile-time.

This sort of 'direct use of a primitive' is pretty common for parts of FPGA's which can't easily be 'inferred' from the verilog design behaviour, and which usually vary between FPGA architectures (fpga 'families' if you like).

Yosys treats these like 'black boxes', but you can load a verilog definition so that you can simulate how they behave.

Trivia: the 'SB_' on the front almost certainly meant 'Silicon Blue', who originally designed the ice40 architecture, before being bought up and incorporated into Lattice. You can still find some ice40 chips with the SiliconBlue logo on them.